# User input a number of series as x and y in php/html

Tags: php, html

I am new to **HTML** and **PHP** and I need to design an **HTML/PHP** user input that can accept a series of numbers like this:

input your x: then there is a box to enter the numbers. User should input numbers separated by commas like 1,2,3,4 (all at once can be typed in the box and submitted)

I know that I can use `GET` or `POST` in method attribute. But I do not know how to define number series. The next step is to separate individual numbers so I can not define it as text unless I find a trick that can separate text by, and convert to numbers (so input is text but there is a code that separate and convert text to individual numbers like 1 and 2 and 3 and 4).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: _"unless I find a trick that can separate text by ,"_ - [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Comment: what seems to be the problem? show us your effort first by posting what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function like this;

```
$numbers = explode(',', $_GET['numbers']);
```

$numbers is array of the numbers that user entered.